# How do I get LUA syntax highlighting inside of XML quotes in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: xml, lua, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting

I have a situation where I end up coding a lot of LUA inside of XML strings,
[and it looks quite ugly, to be honest.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpAlH.png)
It would be extremely nice to be able to have [syntax highlighting for the LUA, since that's the main focus of the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IviYd.png); I'm fairly sure that this is supported (apparently SQL is highlighted inside of PHP in some cases), but I have looked for how to edit the syntax files and I'm honestly just stumped. Some of the solutions even seem to suggest I need to edit a `.tmLanguage` file, but I can't find any of those files and none of the `sublime-syntax` files look like the same kind of format.

If it makes the situation any easier, the strings containing the LUA *always* begin with `"%function(self)` and they *always* end with `end"`, and I only really want this highlighting functionality in XML.

Comment: please can you share an example XML file with LUA embedded that I can copy and paste - I will have a go at updating the syntax definition and answer with detailed steps of how to do it :)

Comment: [Here you go,](http://hastebin.com/vawicezuxu.xml) thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to open the XML syntax definition for editing. I will explain how to do that. Anything referring to a `tmLanguage` (XML format) file is out-of-date, Sublime Text 3 now uses `sublime-syntax` (YAML format) files for all it's default syntax highlighting.

I would recommend cloning the official git repo https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages (please follow the instructions in the repo's readme, which details how to clone a package in such a way that Sublime Text picks it up) so that you will be able to include any future changes made to the official version into your version using git (because we are overriding the default one that would get upgraded automatically with ST, with this customized version). (Basically, you want the `XML` folder from the repo in your Sublime `Packages` folder, which is accessible from ST by navigating to the `Preferences -> Browse Packages` menu item.)

The file we are interested in is `XML/XML.sublime-syntax`. As you can see, it is full of regular expressions. The one we are most interested in is where it parses XML attributes.

Search for `double-quoted-string:`. Immediately under this line, paste in the following:

```
- match: '"(?=%function\(self\))'
  scope: string.quoted.double.xml punctuation.definition.string.begin.xml
  push:
    - clear_scopes: true
    - match: '"'
      scope: string.quoted.double.xml punctuation.definition.string.end.xml
      pop: true
    - include: scope:source.lua
```

Note that the first character (the `-` before `match`) should line up with the original `- match: '"'` that was there.

Save it. And that's it!

---

Basically, what we are doing, is:

- before the syntax checks for a plain double quote (`"`), it will look for a double quote followed by the literal string `%function(self)`. It does this using a lookahead, so that it can then `include` the `source.lua` scope, and have that `%function(self)` text/code highlighted properly as LUA (along with the rest of the LUA code).
- Note that it uses `clear_scopes: true` to ensure that the LUA code doesn't look like XML text/attributes.
- Then, it looks for the closing XML attribute quote (`"`) and "pops" the context off the stack, back to being inside a plain XML tag. (I chose to look for the `"` without `end` before it, so that `end` would still be picked up by the LUA syntax definition. Otherwise we would have to duplicate the match regex and scope for it in the XML syntax, which isn't ideal.)

(You might want to create a new branch in your local repo, and commit these changes, to make it easier to merge future official changes in.)

[image: lua inside xml]

Comment: You're welcome. :) I'm probably missing a few connecting-dots, like how I knew to use scope `source.lua`, for example - so please feel free to ask for clarification on anything here in the comments :)